# Apply service to controller- Unknown provider: ModalSrvProvider <- ModalSrv

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I found similar example: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1551 but in my case something is not working.
I have very simple service:

```
/*jshint esnext: true */

class ModalSrv {
    constructor($scope) {
    }

    open(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.modalClass = 'open';
    }
}

ModalSrv.$inject = ['$scope'];

export default ModalSrv;
```

And also very simple controller:

```
/*jshint esnext: true */

import ModalSrv from './ModalSrv'


class ShowVersionCtrl {
    contructor($rootScope, $scope, $http, ModalSrv) {
        $scope.showVersion = () => {
            $http.get('/my_data.json').then(
                result => {ModalSrv.open(result.data);} 
            );
        }
    }
}

ShowVersionCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'ModalSrv'];

export default ShowVersionCtrl;
```

But I get `Unknown provider: ModalSrvProvider <- ModalSrv` How to make this kind of service work with this controller?

Comment: You can't inject scope inside service, you should just send data back from service method, & then bind that data in controller only..

Comment: _"I found similar example"_ In that example `angular.module().xxx` is called, so ...

Comment: Sorry, Angular for the first time is for me like walking in the fog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS, you should register your created Service with some name. You created class, and you need to register this class as angular module.

```
import ModalSrv from './ModalSrv'

angular.module(app, []).service('modalService', ModalSrv);
```

So you said to angular, that this class should be taken once `modalService` mentioned as dependency. And angular will create an single instance of `ModalSrv` class.

And finally your code will be look like this:

```
/*jshint esnext: true */


class ShowVersionCtrl {
    contructor($rootScope, $scope, $http, modalService) {
        $scope.showVersion = () => {
            $http.get('/my_data.json').then(
               result => {ModalSrv.open(result.data);} 
            );
        }
    }
}

ShowVersionCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'modalService'];

export default ShowVersionCtrl;
```